# Who am I? can you recognize me by the given hints?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I am known for the "*Worst generation*" 
 
a part of me known for the naval battle. 
I am also known for White City. 
I am the survivor of the Most Dangerous Disease.

Who am I? I will add more hints if failed to recognize me.

Hint1:

> 'D' plays important part in my name.

Comment: Might be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_City

Comment: Apparently heart disease is the disease that kills the most people according to the WHO. (https://www.healthline.com/health/top-10-deadliest-diseases#cad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> Trafalgar D. Law

- part of "Worst Generation"
- Born in White City
- Survived Tree Fever

Comment: yes, you are right but still, if you can add the navel battle part and most dangerous deases then it will be perfect.

Comment: I'm actually not to sure about the other one

Comment: Trafalgar. (trəˈfælɡə; Spanish trafalˈɣar) n. (Placename) Cape Trafalgar a cape on the SW coast of Spain, south of Cádiz: scene of the decisive naval battle (1805) in which the French and Spanish fleets were defeated by the British under Nelson, who was mortally wounded.